# R change factor in a dataset

Tags: r, function, factors

I have a data frame contr_factors, with 1932 rows and the following columns: 
state, unarmed, not_flee, white_victim, attacked. I want to change the factors in the data set and I wrote this code:

```
contr_factors$unarmed <- as.factor(contr_factors$unarmed)
levels(contr_factors$unarmed) <- c("Armed", "Unarmed")
contr_factors$white_victim <- as.factor(contr_factors$white_victim)
levels(contr_factors$white_victim) <- c("Non-white", "White")
contr_factors$not_flee <- as.factor(contr_factors$not_flee)
levels(contr_factors$not_flee) <- c("Flee", "Not flee")
contr_factors$attacked <- as.factor(contr_factors$attacked)
levels(contr_factors$attacked) <- c("Not attack", "attack")`
```

But I want to make my code sorter and I tried this function:

```
change_factors <- function(df, df_col, `name1`, `name2`) {
as.factor(df$df_col) 
levels(df$df_col) <- c("name1", "name2")
}
change_factors(contr_factors, not_flee, `Flee`, `Not flee`)
```

But I have an error:
Error in levels(df$df_col) <- c("name1", "name2") : 
  attempt to set an attribute on NULL.

Comment: You should use `df[[df_col]]` not `df$df_col` then call the function with `"not_flee"` (with quotes).

Comment: There is already a built in function that does what you want. `factor(contr_factors$unarmed, levels = c("Armed", "Unarmed")`. It also has a `labels` argument which allows you to re-label the levels if you want.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you were to provide some sample code. That could make this easier, but you have two options.

```
 change_factors <- function(df, df_col, `name1`, `name2`) {
       as.factor(df[,df_col]) 
       levels(df[,df_col] <- c("name1", "name2")
       }

 change_factors(contr_factors, "not_flee", `Flee`, `Not flee`)
```

The other option is to take Rich's advice. The issue is that the $ has trouble taking a string afterwards. You could consider using the lazyeval package to make this easier, or using different methods to access columns in a data-frame.